# Angularjs directive - keydown listener is invoked with delay

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive `make-caps` applied to an input element. It will convert all chars in the input box to uppercase as the user types it.

Now, the directive has its event listener attached to `keydown` event.

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs){
    element.bind('keydown', function(event){
        //$timeout(function(){
            element[0].value = element[0].value.toUpperCase();
        //});
    })
}
```

Uppercasing works for all, except that the last character is left out. If user types `elle`, it will render `ELLe`. I am able to fix it by wrapping the code inside `$timeout` block, but i am curious why doesn't the view get updated, when i set `element[0].value`

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DEBWIU77D4UlmMf5B3MB?p=preview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `keydown` events are fired before the new character is added to the value of the input. Use `keyup`

```
element.bind('keyup', function(event){
    element[0].value = element[0].value.toUpperCase();

})
```